# how to keep the footer sticky at the bottom always?

Tags: sticky-footer

How can i keep the footer sticky at the bottom when that certain page doesn't have enough content in it. Bootstrap class "sticky bottom doesn't work properly in such cases"

Answer (score 0):

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
```

Add these to body, and these to footer

```
<footer class="mt-auto">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap 4.x**

```
<div class="navbar fixed-bottom"></div>
```

Don't forget to add

```
body { padding-bottom: 70px; }
```

or otherwise the page content may be covered